# Restarting my server using an external program

Tags: java, python, powershell, batch-file, server

I have a server when it runs it starts as bat file and display to me the logs and i can write some commands in it. i wanna restart it daily the problem is to restart i need to type "server.restart" after it shutdowns the program will not start because it terminated itself.

Now what im trying to achieve is creating a external program that will write in bat file "server.restart" after its closed or after a set of time the program will run the bat file again.

How can i make program that will write in bat file?
Some suggested using shell but im more familiar using java, python or c++

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make program that will write in bat file? Some suggested using shell but im more familiar using java, python or c++.

Probably no.  The BAT file is probably locked (by the OS) while it is being executed.

Even if you could write to it, it is unclear what would happen:

- The batch file processor (e.g. cmd.exe, powershell, etc) may have read and buffered the entire batch file.
- The batch file processor may be waiting for the command that runs the serve to exit before it will process the next command in the BAT file.

A better approach is to write your server to accept control commands via a socket or named pipe, or as HTTP requests, or something similar.  (The server could even watch for updates to a file containing a command file.)

Search for examples.  I'm sure you will find them.

Comment: `The BAT file is probably locked (by the OS) while it is being executed`: no, it isn't. Even a batch file can write to its own end: `echo something >> "%~f0"` (it's even possible to delete it while it runs (probably resulting in an error mesage))

Answer (score 0):

A batch file is essentially code run as if it was run from the windows command prompt.

If you understand clearly what I'm saying, then you could add to the batch script (or call another batch script after the rest has completed) which would only start your server.

You can run a python script by writing the script and them calling it in the batch script directly into python.

To call from command line it's simply

```
python start_server.py
```

You could type that into the command line similarly to test.

Comment: can i use python to write a command into a bat file while its running? like "server.restart"

Comment: Ah, sorry think I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: Depending on what needs to change and how often, you could simply write a new script which is an exact copy of the previous one used, but then add your new commands into it and then archive the old script and then when your new scriptnis run so are your new commands, if that makes sense